# GDAL fails to get SRS authority or SRS code for OziExplorer .map file

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, c

Using GDAL C API (version 2.2.2), I've been unable to extract the Authority (or Authority Code) from a raster.  I can get the Spatial Reference System, and print the WKT from the SRS, but querying the authority/code from the SRS fails.

Here's the code that I'm using (this is Swift code calling the C APIs):

```
        var pChars: UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>? = nil
        if OSRExportToWkt(_srs, &pChars) != OGRERR_NONE {
            logger.error("FAILED to get WKT string")
        } else if pChars != nil {
            print(String(cString: pChars!))
        }
        if let _ = OSRGetAuthorityName(_srs, nil) {
            print("GOT AUTHORITY")
        } else {
            print("FAILED TO GET AUTHORITY")
        }
        if let _ = OSRGetAuthorityCode(_srs, nil) {
            print("GOT CODE")
        } else {
            print("FAILED TO GET CODE")
        }
```

Here's the output that I get:

```
PROJCS["unnamed",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]
FAILED TO GET AUTHORITY
FAILED TO GET CODE
```

Below is the full content of the .map file.  The corresponding .png file does exist and is valid.

If I load up the raster, and then manually create a new VRT from it and manually replace the VRT's SRS (with EPSG:3857), then it works fine.  But my app's users shouldn't have to go through all this just to work with a raster that is already georeferenced.

Why is the authority and code missing from this SRS?  How can I rectify this?

```
OziExplorer Map Data File Version 2.2
some_file_name.png
some_file_name.png
1 ,Map Code,
WGS 84,WGS 84,   0.0000,   0.0000,WGS 84
Reserved 1
Reserved 2
Magnetic Variation,,,E
Map Projection,Mercator,PolyCal,No,AutoCalOnly,No,BSBUseWPX,No
Point01,xy,    0,    0,in, deg, 39, 25.662443, N, 76, 50.302734, W, grid, , , ,N
Point02,xy, 9215,    0,in, deg, 39, 25.662443, N, 76, 26.574841, W, grid, , , ,N
Point03,xy, 9215, 5887,in, deg, 39, 13.937183, N, 76, 26.574841, W, grid, , , ,N
Point04,xy,    0, 5887,in, deg, 39, 13.937183, N, 76, 50.302734, W, grid, , , ,N
Point05,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point06,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point07,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point08,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point09,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point10,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point11,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point12,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point13,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point14,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point15,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point16,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point17,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point18,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point19,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point20,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point21,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point22,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point23,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point24,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point25,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point26,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point27,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point28,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point29,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Point30,xy,     ,     ,in, deg,  ,  , grid, , , ,N
Projection Setup,,,,,,,,,,
Map Feature = MF ; Map Comment = MC     These follow if they exist
Track File = TF      These follow if they exist
Moving Map Parameters = MM?    These follow if they exist
MM0,Yes
MMPNUM,4
MMPXY, 1,     0,     0
MMPXY, 2,  9215,     0
MMPXY, 3,  9215,  5887
MMPXY, 4,     0,  5887
MMPLL, 1, -76.838379, 39.427707
MMPLL, 2, -76.442914, 39.427707
MMPLL, 3, -76.442914, 39.232286
MMPLL, 4, -76.838379, 39.232286
MOP,Map Open Position,0,0
MM1B, 3.707321
IWH,Map Image Width/Height, 9216, 5888
```